# CakePHP AJAX does not updating div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I am new to cakephp. I am using cakephp version 2.3. Having problem using ajax to auto updating  tag, it is just not working.

Here is my **CustomersController.php**

```
public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Js');
public $components = array('Session', 'Paginator', 'RequestHandler');
public function index() {
    $this->set('data', 'initial-value');
}
public function updatedata() {
    $this->set('data', 'updated-value');
}
```

And here is my **index.ctp**

```
<h2>Customers</h2>
<div id="latestvalue"><?php echo $data; ?></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
         alert('start');
         getvalue();
         alert('end');
    });
    function getvalue() {
      $.ajax({
           dataType: 'html',
           url: "/customers/updatedata",
           cache: false,
           success: function(data){
               $('#latestvalue').html(data);
           }
      });
    }
</script>
```

The 'start' and 'end' alert windows did displayed, but the `<div id="latestvalue">` did not updated.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting proper data in response.. ?? Just alert or console.log you Ajax response and see whether it is correct.

Comment: yes I got 'initial-value', but not 'update-value'. from the logic flow after displaying 'start' window the div should contains 'update-value' right? but its not, no change in the div. I add console.log inside function(data) in ajax, but how do I see the log?

Comment: `success: function(data){
    $('#latestvalue').html(data);
    console.log(data);

}`
After this, before making ajax call hit F12 from your keyboard. This is the developer tool. If firefox then see under console->all tab and if chrome then see under network tab

Comment: In console I got: Request Method: GET, Status Code: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error. My browser is Firefox. Tried changed type to POST, got the same error code (request method changed to POST). This should be very simple ajax, but why is it got error??

Comment: I tried using paginator listing all customer rows, the page navigation which (I believe) is also ajax call is working well. There must be something I missed here....

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself. The caused was that I need to have updatedata.ctp view, because I do not need a view so I simply changed the ajax url to point to my json service, and it is working now.